# How do I control the advancement of labels printed on a Zebra LP2844?

Tags: printing, label-printer

Whenever I print a label on a Zebra LP2844 printer, it prints the label fine, but advances two labels down.

i.e. I print one label, the second one is blank.

How do I manage it so that it only prints one label, advances to the next label ready for printing (rather than advancing two labels as it currently does)

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This brings back old memories of printing on tractor feed labels and forms. The solution depends on the software you are using to print the labels; you may need to provide more information for us to solve the problem.

Some possible causes are

- The wrong type of label is selected, so the printer thinks the label is bigger than it really is.
- The label size (page length) is set manually and is too long.
- The printer driver is out of date and doesn't provide the right information to the printer even if you select the right label type.

If you are writing your own software to print the labels then these may apply:

- You may be sending two commands to advance to the next label.
- You may be printing far enough down the label that the printer knows the end of the label has been passed, so you are just at the start of the second label. When you send a command to advance to the next label, it advances to the end of the second label.

Comment: Yup, I was a few pixels off.  Thanks for the help.